# WordPress Dynamic Page Heiarchy

Tags: wordpress, attributes, parent, dashboard

Typically I go to the dashboard to set a pages parent attribute.
Suppose I am dynamically creating a page so it is not available to edit through the dashboard, is there a way to programmatically set the parent attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the wp_insert_post() function.  It takes a $post array, and you can set the parent ID.
here's the link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

here's an example:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_type'     => 'page',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_parent'   => [ <post ID> ], // Sets the parent of the new post, if any. Default 0.
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

I hope it helps!
--updated with example

Answer (score 1):

Check wp_insert_post -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

You can set post parent via the post_parent argument.